# on the/your way down

Tags: meaning

Everybody wonders who is on his way down or out within a company.

Does on his way down and on his way out have the same meaning? The dictionary definition of on the/your way out is no longer being successful, popular or effective but I can not find the definition of on the/your way down.

Thanks,

fate

Answer (score 2):

Someone who is *on their way down* is no longer a rising star within the company- they're not being actively considered for promotions and are being eclipsed by their peers. It may not mean "down" in a literal sense within the organizational chart, merely relative to their peers. It could be a personal assistant who is on his way down because his boss was passed over for a promotion.

Someone who is *on their way out* is considered to be a prime candidate for the next round of layoffs, or someone who spends their days fine-tuning their resume or surfing the net rather than working in the anticipation of a departure in the near future.